# Xfce - adapt settings according to screen resolution

Tags: linux, debian, xfce

I am developing a Debian-based GNU/Linux distribution for visually/hearing impaired people and for the elder. I chose Xfce as the desktop environment for its highly customizable configurations, ease of use and for being lightweight. The problem is:

I am currently using a 1400x900 monitor to test the system. I have 3 panels:

- 1st at the bottom, with Window buttons, the Whisker menu and 4 launchers (Log Out, Magnifier, Virtual Keyboard and Orca Screen Reader);
- 2nd in the top-right corner of the previous panel, with date/time, trash applet, volume control and notification area;
- 3rd centered in the left, with quick launchers. This panel is hidden and appears when the mouse cursor touches the left area of the screen.

I also put 4 launchers in the bottom of the desktop (LibreOffice, Mousepad, Iceweasel and Thunar), and set their size to 70.

The DPI value is 140.

Everything is fine when I test the system in my 1400x900 monitor, but when I do it in a netbook (1024x768 monitor), the panels and icons get all messed up. The only thing that keeps its settings is panel #1, but #2 and #3 don't stay where they should and the icons are completely disproportionate (they barely fit in the screen).

So my question is: Is there a way to keep panel/icon settings among different screen resolutions? Maybe set the size/alignment values to % and not pixels? I want to keep everything proportional with the size of all screens. Any help is appreciated.

Here are some screenshots of the situation:

- This is the desktop in the 1400x900 screen. It should always look like this.

[image: 1400x900]

- This is how it looks in the 1024x768 netbook screen:

[image]

Thanks in Advance,

Eduardo